# Partitioning table in SQL server based on year criteria

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a partition function that will partition the table by year column in sql server. PeriodEndDate is the year column which is of datatype datetime. I would need to extract the year field for example Year(PeriodEndDate).

The criteria is 
1. I need to store data of the last five years. So considering this year is 2017, I should have following five tables

```
 a. table_2017
 b. table_2016
 c. table_2015
 d. table_2014
 e. table_2013
```

2. When it is 2018, i should be able to create partition for table 2018 onwards.

Can somebody show me how to create the partition function based on this criteria. Is this all I need for creating partition or do I need to create filegroups and files as well. Once I create the partition how does it get associated with the table.

I am looking for a good working solution

Comment: Partioning doesn't create tables seperately..For your requirement , you may create some script which does this

Comment: Oh my bad. I thought partitioning creates physical tables on the disk. If thats not the case fine but I need to implement partitioning of the table regardless. I need help with the function

Comment: So, you need 5 separate tables or partitioning? (_The data of partitioned tables and indexes is divided into units that can be spread across more than one filegroup in a database._)

Comment: I need partitioning